# ZFS Snapshots (Missing Incremental)

Tags: solaris, zfs, snapshot, solaris-11

Assume two Zpools on Solaris 11.3.  **Pool A** and **Pool B**.

**Pool A** contains **PoolA/FileSystem1@Snap3**

**Pool B** contains **PoolB/FileSystem1@Snap1** and **PoolB/FileSystem1@Snap2**

Is there a way to update **Pool B** with **FileSystem1@Snap3**?

Comment: What's the history of the pools, filesystem, and snapshots?  In other words, how did you get to this state?

Comment: @AndrewHenle PoolA had a year worth of daily snaps.  Nightly, it would send those snaps to PoolB over SSH.  I needed to delete ~15TB of files from PoolA but needed to delete the snaps as well, otherwise the space wouldn't free up.  After deleting the files, I deleted all the snapshots, forgetting that to send that night's incremental it needed two snapshots.  I should have deleted the files, taken a snapshot, sent an incremental, and then deleted all snapshots that existed before the file deletion.

Comment: There might be a way to avoid sending the entire pool again, but I can't figure it out.  Offhand, I'd think the easiest thing to do is just to send a replication stream of the latest snapshot of the entire pool A to pool B instead of an incremental stream, and if it takes more than a day catch up the incremental snapshots by hand. I'd take a backup of pool B first, especially if that's your "backup" for pool A.